# Find out encryption type

Tags: encryption, script

I have a program im using (Eyebeam)
and im trying to create a script for my users to automate some process.
im trying to figure out the encryption type in the settings file.
I tried creating few password and looks at how the file saves them. example:

hello

2d2a5c4b315457c0ffba6d802b9a182b7be72288aecc452bd58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3

1

2541081c1fdbfefe5134d15154e06d86146d3130b3162c8cd58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3d58a8f2c1b335d8fef70e149a7f9b43cbb2cede09139d3d3

any idea?

Comment: Both your examples are identical (and their contents don't seem to contain any information), so maybe the password isn't stored in that field at all?

Comment: sorry, edited correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's very clear that this is plain hex and not a more complex encoding like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). This can be trivially converted back to binary using `xxd -r -p`.

The first hint comes from the fact that the majority of these strings are identical (only the first 2 lines are different):

```
$ diff -Nurp <( xxd -r -p < a.txt | hexdump -Cv ) <( xxd -r -p < b.txt | hexdump -Cv )
--- /dev/fd/63  2020-08-14 17:04:24.929187593 +0100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2020-08-14 17:04:24.929187593 +0100
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-00000000  2d 2a 5c 4b 31 54 57 c0  ff ba 6d 80 2b 9a 18 2b  |-*\K1TW...m.+..+|
-00000010  7b e7 22 88 ae cc 45 2b  d5 8a 8f 2c 1b 33 5d 8f  |{."...E+...,.3].|
+00000000  25 41 08 1c 1f db fe fe  51 34 d1 51 54 e0 6d 86  |%A......Q4.QT.m.|
+00000010  14 6d 31 30 b3 16 2c 8c  d5 8a 8f 2c 1b 33 5d 8f  |.m10..,....,.3].|
 00000020  ef 70 e1 49 a7 f9 b4 3c  bb 2c ed e0 91 39 d3 d3  |.p.I...<.,...9..|
 00000030  d5 8a 8f 2c 1b 33 5d 8f  ef 70 e1 49 a7 f9 b4 3c  |...,.3]..p.I...<|
 00000040  bb 2c ed e0 91 39 d3 d3  d5 8a 8f 2c 1b 33 5d 8f  |.,...9.....,.3].|
```

As the rest of the string is a repeating 24-byte pattern, I would guess that the key is 192 bit, and that the encryption might be [AES-192](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)... It's also somewhat clear that they're probably using ECB mode (each block is encrypted independantly) which is not really suitable here as it leaks the password prefix and approximage length... compared to the CBC mode where each previous block affects the following blocks, a single character change would result in an entirely different output. See the [block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Common_modes) Wikipedia page for more details.

[image: ECB mode]

[image: CBC mode]

[image: ECB vs. other modes example]

Working backwards from the end of the file, we can get our hands on the stable output:

```
$ xxd -r -p < a.txt | hexdump -Cv | tail -n 5
000003d0  bb 2c ed e0 91 39 d3 d3  d5 8a 8f 2c 1b 33 5d 8f  |.,...9.....,.3].|
000003e0  ef 70 e1 49 a7 f9 b4 3c  bb 2c ed e0 91 39 d3 d3  |.p.I...<.,...9..|
000003f0  d5 8a 8f 2c 1b 33 5d 8f  ef 70 e1 49 a7 f9 b4 3c  |...,.3]..p.I...<|
00000400  bb 2c ed e0 91 39 d3 d3                           |.,...9..|
```

The repeating 24 bytes / 192 bits are `d5 8a 8f 2c 1b 33 5d 8f ef 70 e1 49 a7 f9 b4 3c bb 2c ed e0 91 39 d3 d3`.

This is confirmed further given that `b.txt` has only a 1-byte input, and we can see the first 24 bytes (192 bits) of the file don't match the stable output...

More details on the issues of ECB are in this great answer: [Why shouldn't I use ECB encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946/50424)

---

> I'm trying to figure out the encryption type in the settings file

We can be quite confident that it's ECB with a 192-bit key... and *reasonably* confident that it's AES.

So... probably AES-192-ECB

> I'm trying to create a script for my users to automate some process

Unfortunately, as you don't have key, given current compute power it is for all intents and purposes "*impossible*" to brute force the key and permit decryption - or even the encryption in place of the original system as you'd like to do.

Given that they've made the mistake of using ECB, you may find that the key isn't too difficult to locate and extract from the system... what is Eyebeam? A cloud service, local software or a phyiscal device? Do you have access to the software/firmware? etc...

Comment: First: Wow what a king, thank you so much for your deep answer i mean WOW... Eyebeam is a softphone program, Counterpath Eyebeam, it has a config file saved localy on user's computer, sometimes this file get damaged, i wanted to create a script that by clicking it writes that file again, depending on user's password.

Comment: If you're just wanting to reinstate a file / password, then you should be able to write this data directly in place. The data you've provided includes not integrity checks / message authentication, so unless that is elsewhere, you're good to go.